# SQLite UPDATE statement is not working inside AFTER INSERT Trigger (Android, Room)

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-trigger, fts4

My SQL:

this is not working: I want this trigger to work.

```
CREATE TRIGGER sync_VerseSearch AFTER INSERT ON `VerseTranslation`
BEGIN
UPDATE VerseSearch SET text = VerseSearch.text || ' \n ' || NEW.text WHERE VerseSearch.verse_id = NEW.verse_id;
END
```

Here `VerseTranslation` model has `verse_id` and also `VerseSearch` table has data corresponding to each verse_id.

But when I'm using INSERT statement in the AFTER INSERT trigger it's working
and UPDATE statement in the AFTER UPDATE trigger also working too:
example:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER sync_VerseSearch AFTER INSERT ON `VerseTranslation`
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO VerseSearch (verse_id, text) VALUES(NEW.verse_id + 10000, NEW.text);
  END


 CREATE TRIGGER sync_VerseSearch AFTER UPDATE ON `VerseTranslation`
  BEGIN
  UPDATE VerseSearch SET text = VerseSearch.text || ' \n ' || NEW.text WHERE VerseSearch.verse_id = NEW.verse_id;
  END
```

added +10000 in insert because there is already data in VerseSearch table with each corresponding verse_id(6236) so it does not unique Constraint error for primary key(verse_id).

Problem is opposite ACTION(UPDATE statement in INSERT trigger) not working;

Model Structure:

```
VerseTranslation {
  @PrimaryKey(autogenerate=true)
  id: Int,
  verse_id: Int, // is not primary key // it is not unique, same verse_id multiple times.
  source_id: Int,
  text: String
}

VerseSearch {
  @PrimaryKey
  verse_id: Int, // here it is primary key // it's unique here
  text: String // here I want to Concat(via trigger) all values(and future insert values) in VerseTranslation.text where match verse_id
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger's have to have unique names.

You have also omitted **`;`** at the end of the INSERT.

The following appears to include be what you want:-

Using :-

```
-- CLEAN EVRYTHING UP
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS sync_VerseSearch;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS sync_VerseSearch_ai;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS sync_VerseSearch_au;
    DROp TRIGGER IF EXISTS sync_VerrseSearch_aiu;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS VerseSearch;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS VerseTranslation;

-- CREATE ITEMS
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS VerseSearch (verse_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, text TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS VerseTranslation (verse_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, text TEXT);

CREATE TRIGGER sync_VerseSearch_ai AFTER INSERT ON `VerseTranslation`
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO VerseSearch (verse_id, text) VALUES(NEW.verse_id + 10000, NEW.text);
        UPDATE VerseSearch SET text = VerseSearch.text || ' \n ' || NEW.text WHERE VerseSearch.verse_id = NEW.verse_id;
  END
;
CREATE TRIGGER sync_VerseSearch_au AFTER UPDATE ON `VerseTranslation`
  BEGIN
  UPDATE VerseSearch SET text = VerseSearch.text || ' \n** ' || NEW.text WHERE VerseSearch.verse_id = NEW.verse_id;
  END
;

    /*
    CREATE TRIGGER sync_VerseSearch AFTER INSERT ON `VerseTranslation`
        BEGIN
        UPDATE VerseSearch SET text = VerseSearch.text || ' \n ' || NEW.text WHERE VerseSearch.verse_id = NEW.verse_id;
        END
    ;
    */

-- TESTING THE TRIGGERS
    INSERT INTO VerseSearch VALUES(null,'VSFred'),(null,'VSMary'),(null,'VSAnne'),(null,'VSJohn');
    SELECT * FROM VerseTranslation;
SELECT * FROM VerseSearch;

INSERT INTO VerseTranslation VALUES(null,'Fred'),(null,'Mary'),(null,'Anne'),(null,'John');
SELECT * FROM VerseTranslation;
SELECT * FROM VerseSearch;
UPDATE VerseTranslation SET text = text||'**TEST**' WHERE NOT instr(text,'**TEST**');
SELECT * FROM VerseTranslation;
SELECT * FROM VerseSearch;
```

## Results

### 1st Select :-

[image]

- No translations as yet

### 2nd Select :-

[image]

- searches added no triggering

### 3rd Select after translations :-

[image]
 - tranalations added so will trigger changes to search

### 4th searches changed and added due to triggering

[image: ![enter image description here]

## 5th translations updated

[image]

## 6th out of range searches added

[image]

## Alternative :-

```
CREATE TRIGGER sync_VerseSearch_ai AFTER INSERT ON `VerseTranslation`
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO VerseSearch (verse_id, text) VALUES(NEW.verse_id + 10000, NEW.text);
  UPDATE VerseSearch SET text = VerseSearch.text || ' \n ' || NEW.text WHERE VerseSearch.verse_id = NEW.verse_id;
  END
;
CREATE TRIGGER sync_VerseSearch_au AFTER UPDATE ON `VerseTranslation`
  BEGIN
  UPDATE VerseSearch SET text = VerseSearch.text || ' \n** ' || NEW.text WHERE VerseSearch.verse_id = NEW.verse_id + 10000;
  END
;
```

- this may be more suitable as they will be sequenced INSERT then UPDATE.

Comment: In my question the first SQL Trigger(updating data inside AFTER INSERT Trigger) is not working, I want that to work.